# Can I upgrade my vRAM on HP Elitebook?

Tags: laptop, vram

I have HP Elitebook 8770w, i7 and Quadro k3000m with 2 GB of vRAM. Can I Uprgade it to 4 GB or more? 2GB of vRam is actually enough to run basic programs, but when I run more of them at the s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, video cards with dedicated memory can't be upgraded compared to integrated video cards that share their memory with the system RAM which can be set to the quantity desired by the user in the BIOS/UEFI. So I would say that it is not possible in your case but you should take a look in the BIOS/UEFI just in case I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. That laptop, and most laptops with a dedicated GPU, have the video RAM and GPU built into the mainboard of the computer and it cannot be upgraded or changed. Laptops are not as upgradable as most desktop machines.

In general adding more memory will not make your programs run faster anyway. This video card is not very powerful, roughly equivalent to a GeForce GTX 860M or GT 740, it should run most games at low settings but is not a performance card. Workstations graphics are more for multiple monitor support or other graphics manipulation rather than frame rate performance and texture fill like games use.